# What is the difference between bash string with quote and without quote

Tags: string, bash

Does it matter to surround string content in quote marks in Bash scripts? 
Consider the following two variables:

```
str1=hei
str2="Hi"
```

Which of the above ways of defining a string literal is preferred in bash and why?

Comment: Both work fine - but it's best practice to quote strings. Bash deals with spaces in various ways - once you have spaces in your strings then skipping the quotes will tend to break things...

Comment: See: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/6862601) and [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/6862601).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all.  Purely for stylistic reasons, many people will say that using the quotes is preferred.  The only purpose of quotes in bash is to control word splitting and variable interpolation. (and special characters....it's probably a rather long list).  Since the right hand side of your equation has no variables and no special characters, the quotes are not necessary.

Consider the following:

```
sp='this is a string with spaces'   #1
sp=this' is a st'rin"g wit"h\ spaces  #2 same as #1
v=$sp     #3
v="$sp"   #4  equivalent to #3
v='$sp'   #5  assign literal string $sp
```

2 and 3 are stylistically horrible, but completely valid.  Since word splitting does not happen in a variable assignment, #3 and #4 are equivalent.  The purpose of the double quotes in a string with whitespace is to prevent word-splitting (that can also be achieved with a backslash). That is, `sp=this is a string` would parse as an attempt to invoke a command `is` with the arguments `a` and `string` and the environment variable `sp` set to the value of `this`, but using quotes prevents that.  The reason to use double quotes instead of single quotes is to allow variable interpolation.  When a string has neither variables nor whitespace, there is no reason (other than style) to use any quotes at all.

Personally, I find the style of over-quoting to be a bit excessive.  Unless a person uses quotes on an interactive prompt with command like `ls "/p/a/t/h"`, I see no reason to use quotes when they aren't necessary.  For consistency, those people advocating using quotes should always type `"ls" "/p/a/t/h"`, and I've never known anyone to quote commands like that.  OTOH, shell quoting rules can be a bit arcane (see #2 above!), and if there's any doubt, use quotes.

Comment: Comprehensive! Thanks.